# Displaying a message from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-alertdialog, popupwindow

I wrote a simple class that extends BroadcastReceiver to handle an incoming call and get the caller's number. Now I want to display that number in a popup window or something similar. I've tried to display an alert dialog or open an activity but my app crashed. Then I read that it's not a good idea to start dialog from a BroadcastReceiver class. I need you to advice me how to correctly display the caller's number on the screen when there's an incoming call. This is my Broadcast Receiver class:

```
package com.example.nrsearch;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public CallReceiver() {
    }

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i("CallReceiverBroadcast", "onReceive() is called. ");
    TelephonyManager teleMgr = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    PhoneStateListener psl = new PhoneStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            Log.i("CallReceiverBroadcast", "onCallStateChanged() is called. ");
            switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                Log.i("CallReceiverBroadcast", "Incoming call caught. Caller's number is " + incomingNumber + ".");
            }
        }
    };
    teleMgr.listen(psl, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    teleMgr.listen(psl, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
}
}
```

Comment: How did you make it work? You commented on one of the answers below that you got it working with some other code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to show a dialog from inside your onReceive of the BroadcastReceiver, you have to start a transparent activity with an alert dialog and NEVER called setContentView(). The activity will have an transparent view and only the alert dialog will show..

Your Broadcast Receiver onReceive

```
@Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
Log.i("CallReceiverBroadcast", "onReceive() is called. ");
TelephonyManager teleMgr =(TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
PhoneStateListener psl = new PhoneStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        Log.i("CallReceiverBroadcast", "onCallStateChanged() is called. ");
        switch (state) {
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
            Log.i("CallReceiverBroadcast", "Incoming call caught. Caller's number is " +incomingNumber + ".");
 //start activity which has dialog  
    Intent i=new Intent(context,DialogActivity.class);
     i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
     context.startActivity(i);
        }
    }
};
teleMgr.listen(psl, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
teleMgr.listen(psl, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
}
```

And your DiaLogActivity

```
  public class DialogActivity extends Activity 
{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  //dont call setcontent view

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?").setCancelable(
        false).setPositiveButton("Yes",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        }).setNegativeButton("No",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
 }

  }
```

Comment: And dont forget to call finish() method on transparent activity.

Comment: Thank you, but I already got it another way. I just started a floating not-full-screen activity with message and button in it. Thank you anyway, I strongly believe I'll use your advice in another situation! It's really helpful.

Comment: if you called finish will get exception of leadkedWindow

Answer (score 3):

I created a `IncomingCallService` service that extends from `BroadcastReceiver` to handle an incoming call and get the caller's number. Now I displayed that Incoming caller number in a popup window like TrueCaller. Its working fine me. Hope it should helpful for you. Please try and let me know. Thanks

**CallReceiver.java**

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    static String IncomingNumber;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        TelephonyManager teleMgr = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        PhoneStateListener psl = new PhoneStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                IncomingNumber = incomingNumber;
                Log.i("CallReceiverBroadcast", "Incoming call caught. Caller's number is " + incomingNumber + ".");
                Intent i = new Intent(context, IncomingCallService.class);
                context.startService(i);
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                Log.i("CallReceiverBroadcast", "CALL_STATE_IDLE");                  
                IncomingCallService.clearView(context);
                // Call Disconnected
                break;

            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                Log.i("CallReceiverBroadcast", "CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK");
                IncomingCallService.clearView(context);
                // Call Answer Mode
                break;
            }
        }
        };
        teleMgr.listen(psl, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        teleMgr.listen(psl, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
    }
}
```

**IncomingCallService.java:**

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class IncomingCallService extends Service {

    static View view = null;
    static WindowManager wm;
    static LayoutInflater inflater;
    static WindowManager.LayoutParams params;
    private static TextView txtIncomingnumber;
    static boolean processingAction = false;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onCreate();
    params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 350,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    params.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP;
    params.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL;

    wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main,null);

    wm.addView(view, params);
    txtIncomingnumber = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtIncomingnumber);
    txtIncomingnumber.setText("You have Incoming Call from " + CallReceiver.IncomingNumber);

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    public static void clearView(Context context) {
        wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        if(view != null) {
            if(view.isEnabled()){
                wm.removeView(view);
                view = null;
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="#0090FF"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:keepScreenOn="true" >

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtIncomingnumber"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="Incoming Call Number"
    android:textColor="#fff" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.stackoverflow"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" ></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"></uses-permission> 

    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <receiver android:name=".CallReceiver" >                     
        <intent-filter android:priority="99999">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name="com.stackoverflow.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name=".IncomingCallService">
    </service> 
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Thank you, but your code is more unfamiliar to me than the one that was posted by Praveen. Anyway, big thanks for being helpful. I'm sure I'll use your example somewhere else. I'm just a beginner developer so every helpful peace of code is like a treasure for me. Thanks again!