# How to get the Disconnected Phone Number in android PhoneStateListener

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, phone-state-listener

I am using `PhoneStateListener` to listen the call State when we have incoming call, outgoing and disconnect the call. All are working fine. But my question is i want to get the disconnected the phonenumber in `CALL_STATE_IDLE`, `CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK`.

When we have incoming call i can get the incoming phone number. But when the phone call end i cant able to get the disconnected phone number. I am using below code.

Anyone give me some ideas about how to get the phone number is  `CALL_STATE_IDLE`, `CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK`.

```
// Call State Listener
private final class CallStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String inComingNumber) {
        switch (mCallState) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
                    // New Outgoing Call
                } else if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                    System.out.println("New Incoming Call");
                    System.out.println("CallStateListener Incoming Number: " + inComingNumber);
                    // New Incoming Call
                }
                break;

            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    // Call Disconnected
                    System.out.println("CallStateListener Disconnected Number: " + inComingNumber);
                    System.out.println("Call Disconnected");
                } else if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                    // Another Call Waiting
                }
                break;

            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
                    System.out.println("Call Received");
                    System.out.println("CallStateListener Received Number: " + inComingNumber);
                    // Call Received
                } else if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    System.out.println("CallStateListener Missed Number: " + inComingNumber);
                    // Call Missed
                }else if(state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                }
                break;
        }
        mCallState = state;
    }
}
```

When i am using above PhoneStateListener i am getting the log as

```
CallStateListener Incoming Number: 4121312323
CallStateListener Missed Number:
CallStateListener Received Number:
CallStateListener Disconnected Number:
```

I can get only Incoming Call Number in RINGINE State, But I can't get Call received state Phone number, Call Missed State Phone Number and Disconnected Phone Number. Please any help guide me. Thanks

Comment: Are you able to get the state for Phone Pick up by opposite side person ? ( This is just my question ).

Comment: @Kedarnath, Yes. I can get the Call Received state when opposite site person picked my call.

Comment: How ? Can you share the code please ?

Comment: @Kedarnath, Using below code I can get the Call Received state. case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
 System.out.println("Call Received");
 System.out.println("CallStateListener Received Number: " + inComingNumber);
 // Call Received
} else if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
 System.out.println("CallStateListener Missed Number: " + inComingNumber);
 // Call Missed
 }else if(state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
}

Comment: @Kedarnath, I am using the same source. This is i answered another question. Please try this code to get the disconnected call number.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22462726/displaying-a-message-from-broadcastreceiver/22496878#22496878

Answer (score 0):

Try to open activity like this:

```
switch (state) {
case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
    Log.v("idle state", "CALL_STATE_IDLE");
    // CALL_STATE_IDLE ( OpenMissedCallScreen )

    if (ring == true && callReceived == false && CheckMissCall.isRunning== false) {
        flag = true;
        if (prefs.getBoolean("main_state", true))
        {
            Intent inter = new Intent(c, MissCall.class);

        }
    }
    break;
case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
    // CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK ( OpenReceivedCallScreen )
    callReceived = true;
    break;
case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
    ring = true;
    // CALL_STATE_RINGING ( openIncomingCallScreen )
    break;
```